# Electromagnetism and magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism

Would it be possible to fill hollow non-magnetic blocks of metal with ferromagnetic fluids and use magnetic fields to move the blocks in a certain way? I am only asking this because I think that if it does work (which it probably does i just need conformation from someone else) i could create some system of electromagnetic fields which changes the direction of the cubes and possibly pulls them together. if i could pull the cubes together i could possibly create small changing magnetic creations, such as a magnetic robot.

Comment: Why does it have to be a ferromagnetic fluid, instead of a soft ferromagnet (i.e. a ferromagnet whose polarization is easily reversed) which will probably have a higher susceptibility (and thus efficiency). Furthermore, moving induces magnetic dipoles in a field is not very efficient (to my knowledge).

Comment: As Sebastian Riese said, there is nothing special about ferrofluids, they are basically just suspensions of ferromagnetic particles in a liquid base. The problem with all ideas to use magnets for more than very local movement (as in lifting magnets and motors) is that all magnetic interactions are dipole interactions, which means that the forces between the interacting objects are falling off with the third power of distance. A doubling of distance basically reduced the amount of force by an order of magnitude. This makes technical applications like yours hard to implement.

Comment: i chose to use ferromagnetic fluids because, if given enough of a magnetic field, they would be the easiest to move different blocks around by changing the amount centered in one area. thanks for asking.

Comment: You are basically opting for an inferior technical solution because you don't understand the actual properties of these materials and how they interact with magnetic fields. If you want to move things magnetically, pick a technical material that is designed to move things, like ferromagnetic alloys for electric motors. These materials have been optimized for these applications and you can not get much better than that.

Comment: im really just trying to find a magnetic way to create an ever changing magnetic robot.

Comment: Why not give every block a few little electromagnets... one for each major axis. Now you can move and rotate them, which would be much harder (impossible?) if you had only passive (induced) magnetism in them.

Comment: ill try both suggestions and see which works better.